# Postgres crosstab confusion

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to achieve the following from my data:

```
docid,  yyyy,   tiOne,  tiTwo,  tiThree,  tiFour
d1      2011    txtA    txtB    txtC
d2      2012    txtD    txtE    txtF      txtG
d3      2013    txtH    txtI    txtJ
d4      2013    txtK
```

This is how to recreate my data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (
  docid   text
, yyyy    int
, timark  text
, txtmark text
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES 
  ('d1', 2011, 'tiOne', 'txtA'), 
  ('d1', 2011, 'tiTwo', 'txtB'), 
  ('d1', 2011, 'tiThree', 'txtC'), 
  ('d2', 2012, 'tiOne', 'txtD'),
  ('d2', 2012, 'tiTwo', 'txtE'),
  ('d2', 2012, 'tiThree', 'txtF'),
  ('d2', 2012, 'tiFour', 'txtG'),
  ('d3', 2013, 'tiOne', 'txtH'), 
  ('d3', 2013, 'tiTwo', 'txtI'), 
  ('d3', 2013, 'tiThree', 'txtJ'), 
  ('d4', 2013, 'tiOne', 'txtK')
;
```

This is my code

```
select *
FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT docid, timark, txtmark
       FROM   t
       ORDER  BY 1,2')  -- needs to be "ORDER BY 1,2" here
AS ct ("docid" text, "timark" text, "txtmark" text);
```

but I'm getting a completely confusing output as follows:

```
docid timark txtmark
d1    txtA   txtC
d2    txtG   txtD
d3    txtH   txtJ
d4    txtK
```

The 'tiOne' data is not well structured, so it is hard to know precisely what is going to be in those columns, so it won't be easy to hard-code those values into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crosstab query alias should contain the column names and types of the result set. 
The result of the source query should be ordered by two columns: row identifier (docid) and category identifier (timark). 
Unfortunately, the alphabetical order of the category names is not the expected one.

In this case use the form of `crosstab` function with two parameters.
The second parameter is a query that selects all categories in an expected order.
This form of `crosstab` allows also to have additional columns (`yyyy`) and properly shows incomplete data.

```
select *
FROM crosstab(
    $$ SELECT docid, yyyy, timark, txtmark
    FROM t
    ORDER BY 1 $$,
    $$ values ('tiOne'), ('tiTwo'), ('tiThree'), ('tiFour') $$)
AS ct ("docid" text, "yyyy" text, "tiOne" text, "tiTwo" text, "tiThree" text, "tiFour" text);

 docid | yyyy | tiOne | tiTwo | tiThree | tiFour 
-------+------+-------+-------+---------+--------
 d1    | 2011 | txtA  | txtB  | txtC    | 
 d2    | 2012 | txtD  | txtE  | txtF    | txtG
 d3    | 2013 | txtH  | txtI  | txtJ    | 
 d4    | 2013 | txtK  |       |         | 
(4 rows)
```